# Angular Electron html

Tags: electron

Tengo estas dos definiciones:

(Esta anda perfecto)

```
win.loadURL(url.format({ pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'), protocol: 'file:', slashes: true }));
```

Y en la segunda ventana hago:

```
child.loadURL(url.format({ pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/indexAdministrador.html'), protocol: 'file:', slashes: true }));
```

Obviamente aparece en blanco, por que `indexAdministrador.html`, nunca llega a `dist/ directorio`.

Answer (score 0):

si estas usando angular, las rutas debes definirlas en el **`app.routing`** de angular, te [dejo un link](https://angular.io/guide/router) para que te documentes

Comment: Aunque teoricamente este enlace conteste la pregunta, es preferible que incluyas las partes esenciales del mismo en la respuesta. Los enlaces pueden caducar y desaparecer. Ademas llevar al usuario a que lea en otro lugar la respuesta, no es la mejor opción. por favor mira el [tour] y tambien [answer]

Comment: Hay 2 opciones en angular, vía router o vía selector. Ambas llegan al mismo destino. Ademas ese no es mi problema, si se fija bien vera que mi problema es otro. Puedo mostrar mas si hiciera falta.

Comment: si seria recomendable que detallaras mejor el problema, como por ejemplo mostrar tu estructura de directorio, y el caso de uso a resolver